# детект браузера и вкладки в нем | Java

Tags: java, google-chrome

Пишу 1 полезную программу и нужно делать проверку открыт ли хром и открыта ли в нем определенная вкладка, лучше будет если еще есть возможность проверки, является ли хром в данный момент активным окном, и является ли нужная мне вкладка активной.

Хелпаните пжл, желательно с примерами или общей структурой

Comment: Меня также интересует возможность отслеживания активных вкладок в браузере с помощью джава, нашёл ли ты ответ?